# Tensor products of finitely generated algebras is a finitely generated algebra (proving a particular case using universal property)

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012070/tensor-product-of-finitely-generated-algebras), I am trying to prove a simpler case:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I \leq R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ an ideal. Let $S:=R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I$. I want to see that:
$$ S \otimes_{R} R[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \simeq S$$
as $R$-modules.

My attempt is to show that $S$ satisfies the universal property of the tensor product. I'm looking for an $R$-linear map $T: S \times R[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \rightarrow S$ such that if $\phi: S \times R[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \rightarrow M$ is an $R$-linear map, then there exists a unique $psi: S \rightarrow M$ with $\phi = \psi T$.

It seems like the only option would be to set $T(f+I, g):= fg+I \in S$ and to set $\psi(f+I):=\phi(f+I, 1)$. However, I would then have to see that $\phi(f+I, g) = \phi(fg+I, 1)$, which is not necessarily true, since $\phi$ is only $R$-linear, not $R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$-linear.

Comment: There is something wrong here. Did you mean $R/I\otimes_R R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\cong S$?

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant that $I$ is an ideal in $R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ but only wrote $R$.

Comment: There is still something wrong. As written, you will have $S\otimes_R R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\cong S[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Ah, is it the case in general that $S \otimes_R R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ = $S[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ for any $R$-algebra $S$? Anyhow, why will I have this?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3655840/422221. Alternatively, let $S=R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$. Then we have the surjection $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to S$, and after tensoring it with $R[y_,\ldots,y_m]$ we get the surjection $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m]\to S\otimes_R R[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$. It remains to identify the kernel of this epimorphism.